# How can I interpret the "controlling terminal" code of ps output?

Tags: ps

The controlling terminal output of ps lists things "Ss+". How can I determine what these codes mean? I tried looking through the ps manual, which is a 30-page document, I found no explanation.

Comment: Why are you calling that “controlling terminal”? Where did you see this term? The “controlling terminal” column doesn't contain things like `Ss+`, it contains things like `tty42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man ps`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

           D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
           R    running or runnable (on run queue)
           S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
           T    stopped by job control signal
           t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
           W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
           X    dead (should never be seen)
           Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

       For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:

           <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
           N    low-priority (nice to other users)
           L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
           s    is a session leader
           l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
           +    is in the foreground process group
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `tt` column from `ps` output and use `tty` command like so:

```
$ps ax |more
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
    1   ??  Ss     4:58.84 /sbin/launchd
   66   ??  Ss     1:05.03 /usr/sbin/syslogd
   67   ??  Ss     0:21.62 /usr/libexec/UserEventAgent (System)


$ps ax |grep bash
81939 s000  S+     0:00.09 -bash
82152 s001  S      0:00.04 -bash
82228 s001  S+     0:00.00 grep -I bash


$tty
/dev/ttys001


$ps ax |grep offlineimap-load
82261 s000  S+     0:00.02 /bin/bash /Users/pbarganski/Documents/bin/offlineimap-load
82417 s001  R+     0:00.01 grep -i offlineimap-load
```

From the above, `tty` command tells me which terminal I am currently in - terminal **'s000'** in this case.

From the last command, you'll notice that the `grep -i` command was run from terminal **s001**, my current terminal window, however, the **offlineimap-load** script is running from controlling terminal **s000** - my first terminal session - which in this case, is simply the first tab terminal in terminal.app.